# pre answer gnome-initial-setup-first-login for all users to be created

Tags: gnome, 22.04, login

Ubuntu 22.04.

Thanks to this [page](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/01/disable-welcome-dialog-ubuntu-22-04), I know how to completely disable the questions that all new user have to answer when they connect for the firs time.

I use this command to create an override:

```
systemctl --global edit gnome-initial-setup-first-login.service
```

The content of the override file is this:

```ini
# The condition will never be true => the service will never run
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=%E/no-such-file-or-directory
```

With that no one will ever have to answer the first login questions.

Now this leaves the default behaviour. So for example the default is to send reports to ubuntu when something goes wrong. How can I have a "don't send the report" behavior for all users not yet created ?